# Show text under img file with php echo

Tags: php, variables, echo

Someone can you tell me how to change my code to show variables in link:

```
echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'"><img src="'.$img.'" /></a>';
```

this shows img file but i want under this img to show title with text. Try this, but don't work:

```
echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'">'.$title'</a>';
```

Comment: You want to show the text instead of the image, or you want to show both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your ending dot.

replace

```
echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'">'.$title'</a>';
```

with

```
echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

Comment: thanks man. how simple but when you don't know... :)

Comment: Your welcome. Accepting this answer will close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
 echo '<a href="download.php?q='.$title.'"><img src="'.$img.'" />'.$title.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
<?php

echo '<a href="download.php?q="'.$title.'"><img src="'.$img.'" /></a>';

?>
```

Comment: the code is working, i want to show text under img file. I know about <?php

Comment: What sort of text? @FmX

Comment: @Krii understand what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use heredoc syntax.

```
echo <<<EOT
 <a href="download.php?q={$title}"><img src="{$img}" /></a>
EOT;
```